# What is the difference between "Run As Android Application" and "Debug As Android Application"?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

Title says all. If you right-click on the folder in the project explorer and go to Run As and Debug As, what would be the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debug mode allows code debugging: halt on breakpoints, variable inspection, line-by-line code execution, whereas Run mode doesn't allow this.

Comment: But in Visual Studio, run and debug mode use difference binaries, one for release and one for debug. However, in eclipse, run and release use the same binary, either both use release binary or both use debug binary. It's very confusing. Could you explain that to me, please?

Comment: @TorosFanny in Java, it is the same binary. The debug mode has to check for breakpoints ... which can realy slow down an application (things like conditional break points are slow).

Answer (score 2):

When you're debugging, Eclipse will stop at breakpoints and allow other debugging actions (view running threads, etc.). When you run, it won't.

If you start by selecting "Run", you can later attach the debugger through the Device view. That will switch to "Debug" mode. Conversely, you can (also through the Device view) detach from a process being debugged and it will switch to "Run" mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
Run as Android application:
```

It will normally run your code without going through the breakpoints you selected.

```
Debug as an Android Application:
```

It will check(or debug) your code via going through all the breakpoints you described or set in your code.It actually checks the code line by line and is the best friend of a developer through which it can test the application well.